# How to use Stripe on non -SSL or http websites?

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, ruby-on-rails-3.2, stripe-payments

I'm using rails 3.2.6, and Stipe for payment.  Is There any possibility to make a payment with out purchasing ssl certificate.  Can i use Stripe page as my payment page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can technically skip SSL by using [stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) but I highly suggest you set up SSL.

What it does is pass credit card information directly to stripe and then stripe will give you a token to use to actually make the charge. Doing it that way means that credit card information never touches your server and you don't have to worry about PCI compliance. However you should still set up SSL to prevent man in the middle attacks.

You can find a good tutorial about how to do this at https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms

There is also an episode on railscasts which explains it more in depth.

Comment: what is that railscasts url

Comment: Doesn't the javascript request that sends the CC information have to be encrypted, which requires an SSL certificate?

Comment: @babaloo Only if it is hitting an unencrypted server which shouldn't be the case if you use it correctly. Stripe.js is communicating directly with stripe via HTTPS.

Comment: Stripe.js requires that you use SSL for your payment form. Details here: https://stripe.com/help/ssl

Comment: @brian is correct. Not using SSL with Stripe is NOT a good advice. See also https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#https "However, in order to protect yourself from certain forms of man-in-the-middle attacks, we suggest that you also serve the page containing the payment form with HTTPS as well. This means that any page that a Checkout form may exist on should start with https:// rather than just http://."

Answer (score 3):

Stripe doesn't provide any sort of hosted form. So unless you have someone else host your payment form over SSL (for example, using one of the [pre-built integrations](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations)), then you'll need to serve your form over SSL. More details on the requirement [here](https://stripe.com/help/ssl).